# Stepper motor holding/cogging torque ratio

Tags: stepper-motor, torque

I need a stepper that has the highest possible holding torque (when power is on) and smallest possible cogging/detent torque (when power is off). This goes back to the holding/cogging ratio - is there a general rule on this ratio or does it differ on a product by product basis?

My application is on a vehicle with dual mode Ackermann steering where I need possibly high torque for automated mode (steering by electronics without human intervention) and I need small cogging torque when in manual mode (steering by hand - the stepper should not have much mechanical resistance so that the steering is not made much harder - ideally zero resistance).

Regarding mechanical solution - because of simplicity the plan is to have a something like a "single stage gear reducer" where there is a big gear on the steering column which directly touches a small gear on the stepper thus giving the stepper quite some power to turn the steering.

Comment: Why not direct drive with brushless DC motor?

Comment: I think a switched reluctance motor might do what you want. I am not an expert on such things, but I believe they have zero cogging (since there is no permanent magnet).

Answer (score 2):

You need a variable-reluctance step motor.  They are available from 24 to 200 steps/revolution.  With zero excitation, they spin freely.  There is no permanent magnet.